# Android Integrate Activity class into Fragment

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, actionbarsherlock

I'm working on an android application that shows the results of a hearing test. It was made a while ago so a lot of the code is depreciated. The old code uses a `TabActivity` which works fine:

```
public class TabbedResultActivity extends TabActivity {
private TabHost mTabHost;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    setContentView(R.layout.tabbed_results);

    setTabs();
}

private void setTabs() {
    mTabHost = getTabHost();

    addTab(R.string.Left_ear, false);
    addTab(R.string.Right_ear, true);
}

private void addTab(int labelId, boolean aRight) {
    Intent intent = createIntent(aRight);
    TabHost.TabSpec spec = mTabHost.newTabSpec("tab" + labelId);        

    View tabIndicator =     LayoutInflater.from(this).inflate(R.layout.tab_indicator, getTabWidget(), false);

    TextView title = (TextView) tabIndicator.findViewById(R.id.title);
    title.setTextSize(14.0f);
    title.setText(labelId);

    spec.setIndicator(tabIndicator);
    spec.setContent(intent);
    mTabHost.addTab(spec);
}

private Intent createIntent( boolean aRight) {
    Intent newIntent = new Intent(getIntent());
    newIntent.putExtra(ResultActivity.IS_RIGHT_EAR, aRight);
    newIntent.setClass(this, ResultActivity.class);
    return newIntent;
}
```

but, the problem I've got it that I have to add an action bar for the menu on newer devices. To make the app compatible on all devices I've used the `ActionBarSherlock` library. This is great but I can't figure out how to add my `ResultsActivity` into the Fragment as I need the `ResultsActivity` to extend from `SherlockFragmentActivity`, but to integrate it into a Fragment, I need to extend the `SherlockFragment` class. If I do this I get loads of errors because it doesn't extend from activity. Here's my original `ResultsActivity` class:

```
public class ResultActivity extends SherlockFragmentActivity {
public static final String IS_RIGHT_EAR = "is_right_ear";
private ArrayList<EarSrt> leftAnswerList;
private ArrayList<EarSrt> rightAnswerList;

private boolean isRightEarTab = true;

private boolean bothEarsBad;
private boolean leftEarBad;
private boolean rightEarBad;


@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    setContentView(R.layout.results_layout);

    Intent intent = getIntent();
    int rowId = intent.getIntExtra(ResultsDatabase._ID, -1);
    if ( rowId != -1 ) {
        ResultsDatabase db = new ResultsDatabase(this);
        String select = "(" + ResultsDatabase._ID + " == " + rowId + ")";
        Cursor c = db.getReadableDatabase().query(ResultsDatabase.TABLE_NAME, null, select, null, null, null,null);
        if ( c.moveToFirst() ) {
            int leftEarColumn = c.getColumnIndex(ResultsDatabase.LEFT_EAR);
            byte[] leftEarByteArray = c.getBlob(leftEarColumn);
            int rightEarColumn = c.getColumnIndex(ResultsDatabase.RIGHT_EAR);
            byte[] rightEarByteArray = c.getBlob(rightEarColumn);
            leftAnswerList = (ArrayList<EarSrt>) ResultsDatabase.deserializeObject(leftEarByteArray);
            rightAnswerList = (ArrayList<EarSrt>) ResultsDatabase.deserializeObject(rightEarByteArray);
        }

    } else {
        byte[] leftEarByteArray = getIntent().getByteArrayExtra(ResultsDatabase.LEFT_EAR);;
        byte[] rightEarByteArray = getIntent().getByteArrayExtra(ResultsDatabase.RIGHT_EAR);
        leftAnswerList = (ArrayList<EarSrt>) ResultsDatabase.deserializeObject(leftEarByteArray);
        rightAnswerList = (ArrayList<EarSrt>) ResultsDatabase.deserializeObject(rightEarByteArray);
    }

    isRightEarTab = getIntent().getBooleanExtra(IS_RIGHT_EAR, true);

    GraphView graphView = (GraphView)findViewById(R.id.graphview);

    if ( isRightEarTab ) {
        graphView.setPoints(rightAnswerList);
        float average = calculateAverage(rightAnswerList);
        graphView.setAverage(average);
    } else {
        graphView.setPoints(leftAnswerList);
        float average = calculateAverage(leftAnswerList);
        graphView.setAverage(average);
    }

    setResults(leftAnswerList, rightAnswerList);
}

private float calculateAverage(List<EarSrt> steps) {
    float srt = 0.0f;
    int length = steps.size();

    for (int i = (int)Math.ceil( (float)length/(float)2); i < length; i++) {
        EarSrt es = steps.get(i);
        srt += es.getSrt();

        //printf("%f ," , [es srt]);
    }

    srt = srt / (length-(float)Math.ceil( (float)length/(float)2));

//      printf("\n%f\n" , srt);

    return srt;
}

private void setResults(List<EarSrt> leftEar, List<EarSrt> rightEar) {
    float esLeft = calculateAverage(leftEar);
    float esRight = calculateAverage(rightEar); 

    leftEarBad = (esLeft > 24.0);
    rightEarBad = (esRight > 24.0);
    bothEarsBad = (leftEarBad && rightEarBad);

    setResultCaption(bothEarsBad, leftEarBad, rightEarBad);
}


/**
 * TODO: this needs finishing
 */
private void setResultCaption(boolean bothEarsBad, boolean leftEarBad, boolean rightEarBad) {
    TextView resultsTextView = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.results_text);
    StringBuilder resultsText = new StringBuilder();
    if (bothEarsBad) {
        resultsText.append(getString(R.string.The_test_indicates_a_possible_hearing_loss));
        resultsText.append(getString(R.string.We_recommend_that_you_visit_a_Hearing_Care_Professional_for_a_comprehensive_hearing_check));
    }else{
        if (leftEarBad) {
            resultsText.append(getString(R.string.The_test_indicates_a_possible_hearing_loss_for_your_left_ear));
            resultsText.append(getString(R.string.We_recommend_that_you_visit_a_Hearing_Care_Professional_for_a_comprehensive_hearing_check));
        } else if (rightEarBad) {
            resultsText.append(getString(R.string.The_test_indicates_a_possible_hearing_loss_for_your_Right_ear));
            resultsText.append(getString(R.string.We_recommend_that_you_visit_a_Hearing_Care_Professional_for_a_comprehensive_hearing_check));      
        }else {
            resultsText.append(getString(R.string.There_is_no_indication_of_hearing_loss));
        }                               
    }

    resultsText.append(getString(R.string.The_results_of_the_hearing_test_are_not_to_be_utilized_as_an_official_outcome_for_assessing_levels_of_hearing_loss_True_hearing_loss_assessments_can_only_be_determined_by_a_licensed_hearing_healthcare_provider));                                  

    resultsTextView.setText(resultsText.toString());
}

public void goToLocate(View aView){
    Intent locate = new Intent( this, LocateActivity.class);
    startActivity(locate);
    finish();
}
}
```

I basically need to integrate this code into two fragment, one for the left ear and one for the right. I've had a go at doing this looking at the Sherlock fragment sample but still cant figure out how to do it.If someone could point me in the right direction that would be really helpful.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Hi you can find the demo and the code exemple for actionBar sherlock :
https://github.com/JakeWharton/ActionBarSherlock/tree/master/actionbarsherlock-samples.
And for your error when you integrate the actionBarSherlock you need to change your activity to fragmentActivity (no change for your project but you can integrate fragment inside your Activity)

Comment: Yeah I've done this but I think I'm doing it wrong. the code above I kept in ResultsActivity class and integrated a ResultsFragment class into that activity. The problem I've got is I don't know how to call the data from the ResultsActivity into the ResultsFragment it's not showing the correct data, I can show you my updated ResultsActivity class if you want to look at that and see what I'm doing wrong

Comment: you should pass data from activity to fragment , so when you should call the display of fragment you need to pass the data in argument: like this : for exemple
            Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
            String url = getWebViewUrl();
            bundle.putString("url", url);
            WebViewFragment webViewFragment = new WebViewFragment();
            // set Fragmentclass Arguments
            webViewFragment.setArguments(bundle);
and in your fragment youshould getfragment to return the value.

Comment: Ok brilliant thanks for your help, hopefully I'll get this right!

Comment: just one thing, I'll have two fragment inside my ResultsActivity class one for each ear then won't I?

Comment: You need to setArgument for each specefic fragment when you need to get data from your activity.